# Do local reference variables add to the GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Say I have one object that is created is some arbitrary class and contained in multiple reference variables in different classes, like so:

```
public void foo(){
    Bar bar = someClass.getBar();
    bar.doSomething();
}
```

Is the bar reference variable added and removed by the GC? I Understand that the actual bar object returned from `someclass.getBar()` won't be collected until all references of it are unreachable, but I'm not sure about the bar reference variable itself. My understanding is that the bar reference variable has a small overhead to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `bar`, which holds a reference to the object instance of `Bar`, is not contained in the heap, but in the stack. The stack frame for this invocation of this method is 'removed' when the method invocation exits. The *variable* `bar` is not ever garbage collected; items in the stack never are.

The object instance itself is allocated on the heap; it will be garbage collected when there are no references to it; if a local variable holds a reference to the object, then the object cannot be garbage collected; if the method has exited, then that reference variable no longer exists, and would not count as a reference to the object.